# Me da error un procedimiento en xampp

Tags: mysql, xampp

> Error Análisis estático: Se encontraron 1 errores durante el análisis.  1. Expresión desaparecida.  (cerca de "ON" en la posición 25) consulta SQL: Copiar SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS MySQL ha dicho: 2014 Commands out of sync;  no puedes ejecutar este comando ahora

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE e2()
BEGIN
DECLARE contador int;
SET contador =3;
bucle: LOOP
IF contador<=8 THEN
SELECT nombre FROM cliente
WHERE id_cli= contador;
SET contador= contador +1;
ITERATE bucle;
ELSE
LEAVE bucle;
END IF;
END LOOP bucle;
END//
CALL e2();
```

> esta es mi sentencia para crear un procedimiento pero al llamarlo me da error y estoy llamando al procedimiento con una sentencia de call e2();

Comment: no es proceso en xamp, es un procedimiento almacenado en MySQL, lo cual es muy diferente.

Comment: Por favor ve a [edit] y añade a tu pregunta cómo estás llamando el procedimiento. Graciasd

Answer (score 0):

El código que muestras en tu pregunta no debería dar el problema que mencionas:

> Expresión desaparecida. (cerca de "`ON`" en la posición 25) consulta
> SQL: Copiar `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS`

Ese problema debe estar en otra parte de tu aplicación, y debes identificar cuál es.

He aquí una prueba de que tu `PROCEDURE` no es errónea:

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE cliente (
  id_cli INT,
  nombre VARCHAR(150)
);
INSERT INTO cliente (id_cli,nombre) VALUES (1,'N1');
INSERT INTO cliente (id_cli,nombre) VALUES (2,'N2');
INSERT INTO cliente (id_cli,nombre) VALUES (3,'N3');
INSERT INTO cliente (id_cli,nombre) VALUES (4,'N4');
INSERT INTO cliente (id_cli,nombre) VALUES (5,'N5');
INSERT INTO cliente (id_cli,nombre) VALUES (6,'N6');
INSERT INTO cliente (id_cli,nombre) VALUES (7,'N7');
INSERT INTO cliente (id_cli,nombre) VALUES (8,'N8');
INSERT INTO cliente (id_cli,nombre) VALUES (9,'N9');

DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE e2()
    BEGIN
        DECLARE contador int;
        SET contador =3;
        bucle: LOOP
            IF contador<=8 THEN
                SELECT 
                    nombre 
                FROM cliente
                WHERE 
                    id_cli= contador;
                SET contador= contador +1;
                ITERATE bucle;
            ELSE
                LEAVE bucle;
            END IF;
        END LOOP bucle;
    END//
```

---

**Query #1**

```
CALL e2();
```

| nombre |
| --- |
| N3 |

| nombre |
| --- |
| N4 |

| nombre |
| --- |
| N5 |

| nombre |
| --- |
| N6 |

| nombre |
| --- |
| N7 |

| nombre |
| --- |
| N8 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cpm4nGRKVkC6Gbwtvs9iSh/0)

---

Si tienes dudas, pregunta en comentarios. **Soy humano, no soy una IA.**